# Parse out a URL with regex operation in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyspark

I have data as follows,

data

```
url
http://hostname.com/part1/part2/part3/a+b+c+d
http://m.hostname.com/part3.html?nk!e+f+g+h&_junk
http://hostname.com/as/ck$st=f+g+h+k+i/
http://www.hostname.com/p-l-k?wod=q+w+e+r+t africa
```

I want to check for first + symbol in the url and move backward until we find a special character such as / or ? or = or any other special character and start from that and go on until we find a space or end of line or & or /.My output should be,

```
parsed
abcd
efgh
fghki
qwert
```

My aim is to find first + in the URL and go back until we find a special character and go front until we find a end of line or space or & symbol.

I am new to regex and still learning it and since it is bit complex, I am finding it difficult to write. Can anybody help me in writing a regex in python, to parse out these?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the expression that works for your sample use cases:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> l = [
...     "http://hostname.com/part1/part2/part3/a+b+c+d",
...     "http://m.hostname.com/part3.html?nk!e+f+g+h&_junk",
...     "http://hostname.com/as/ck$st=f+g+h+k+i/",
...     "http://www.hostname.com/p-l-k?wod=q+w+e+r+t africa"
... ]
>>>
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"[^\w\+]([\w\+]+\+[\w\+]+)(?:[^\w\+]|$)")
>>> for item in l:
...     print("".join(pattern.search(item).group(1).split("+")))
... 
abcd
efgh
fghki
qwert
```

The idea is basically to capture alphanumerics and a plus character that is between the non-alphanumerics and non-plus character or the end of the string. Then, split by plus and join.

[Regex101 link.](https://regex101.com/r/aE6rC1/1)

I have a feeling that it can be further simplified/improved.

Comment: suppose if I have something like this, http://hostname.com/as/ck$st=f+g-h-k-i/, This one gives out f+g. I know this was not the original requirement. But just asking. Can we make it to check for - as well after checking for first + ? by not limiting it to '-' special character alone and all except that?

Comment: @Observer you should add `-` to the expression appropriately. E.g. for a pattern defined as `pattern = re.compile(r"[^\w\+\-]([\w\+\-]+(?:\+|-)[\w\+\-]+)(?:[^\w\+\-]|$)")`, using `re.split()` to split by multiple delimiters: `print("".join(re.split(r"\+|-", pattern.search("http://hostname.com/as/ck$st=f+g-h-k-i/").group(1))))` would produce `fghki`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

So the appropriate regex that shall parse the required characters you wanted is `((.\+)+.)`
I am using Javascript regex here. But, You should be able to implement in py as well.

This regex shall extract you `a+b+c+d` from your first url.
It will need to be processed a little bit more to get `abcd` from `a+b+c+d`.

I will update this with py function in a bit.

Comment: this gives and output of a+b . not a+b+c+d

Comment: @can you consider a,b,c,d as individual words? Here I have given it for simplification. It is taking one letter from both the side. I want to take both the words, until we find a character.

Comment: i mean i just did this in console . `var a = new RegExp(/((.\+)+.)/)`. `a.exec('http://m.hostname.com/part3.html?nk!e+f+g+h&_junk')`

Comment: Guess, you got the complete answer above.

Comment: Yes I got . Thanks a lot :)